# How can I learn the command which will start an application in Unity's 'System Settings' from the command line?

Tags: unity, command-line, settings

How can I discover the command-line name (i.e. actual location) of one of Unity's *System Settings* applications? For example, "*User Accounts*", "*Backup*", "*Appearance*", and so forth?

I wish to know this so I can file a bug report against a particular application!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The details are all in a setting's `*.desktop` file.

- Go to the directory `/usr/share/applications`.
- Find the `*.desktop` file for the setting you are interested in.
- Open the file in `gedit`.

For example, to open **Brightness and Lock** I used the command below.
`gedit '/usr/share/applications/gnome-screen-panel.desktop'`

The content of the file `gnome-screen-panel.desktop` is shown below. The fourth line in the file, `Exec=gnome-control-center screen`, shows that the terminal command to open the **Brightness and Lock** settings windows is `gnome-control-center screen`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Brightness and Lock
Comment=Screen brightness and lock settings
Exec=gnome-control-center screen
Icon=system-lock-screen
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;DesktopSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;X-GNOME-PersonalSettings
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-control-center
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=screen
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.4.1
X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=screen
# Translators: those are keywords for the brightness and lock control-center panel
Keywords=Brightness;Lock;Dim;Blank;Monitor;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-control-center-2.0
```

Comment: FWIW, There is no need to bother with `gksudo` to simply view the contents of the file. You can just use `gedit` and not have to bother with entering a password.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. [*“file content” vs. “file contents”*](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56831/21874)